# IBM Data Catalog doesn't allow to download the Connected Data Asset

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog

IBM Data Catalog doesn't allow to download the Connected Data Asset

I created a connected data from a dashdb connection -> selecting a table.
[image]

Also tried to create a connected data asset from cloudant connection -> selecting document.
[image]

Also uploaded a csv file as data asset.
[image]

None of the above enables Download Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the download button is always disabled.  We are looking to re-enable it for certain assets soon.  More information will be provided when it comes.